# JavaScript callback returning DOMWindow

Tags: javascript, callback

In the following code, when func2b is called, 'this' is the DOMWindow, and not a reference to obj2. Why is func2b loosing it's reference to obj2 as 'this'?

Here's a version on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqzKh/

```
var obj1 = {
  init: function() {
    this.prefix = "Stop!";
    obj2.func2a(this.func1a);
  }
  ,func1a: function(message) {
    console.log(this.prefix + " " + message);
  }
};
var obj2 = {
  func2a: function(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    console.log(this.callback); // Correct reference to obj1.func1a
    obj3.func3a(this.func2b);
  }
  ,func2b: function(message) {
    console.log(this); // Unexpectedly returns DOMWindow
    this.callback(message);
  }
};
var obj3 = {
  func3a: function(callback) {
    callback("Hammer Time.");
  }
}
obj1.init();
```

**SOLUTION**

```
var obj1 = {
  init: function() {
    this.prefix = "Stop!";
    obj2.func2a(this, this.func1a);
  }
  ,func1a: function(message) {
    console.log(this.prefix + " " + message);
  }
};
var obj2 = {
  func2a: function(owner, callback) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.callback = callback;
    obj3.func3a(this, this.func2b);
  }
  ,func2b: function(message) {
    this.callback.call(this.owner, message);
  }
};
var obj3 = {
  func3a: function(owner, callback) {
    callback.call(owner, "Hammer Time.");
  }
}
obj1.init();
```

​

Comment: Functions are not bound, what `this` refers to depends on *how* the function is *called*. Read the [MDN documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: because the `this` binding is per-call-basis and depends on how the function is called, not where the function is stored. If you call a function directly (`fun()`) in non-strict mode, it will always be `window` in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @FelixKling. Not quite sure yet what I need to change in my example to make this work, but I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do:

```
a.f()
```

then a is called 'this' in the body of f.

if you do:

```
f()
```

then window is called 'this' in the body of f.

Edit: as Esailija said:

you're using callback("Hammer Time.") like f() is called in this answer.

Comment: That makes sense theoretically, but how does that translate into my example?

Comment: @scader you're calling the `callback("Hammer Time.")` like `f()` is called in this answer. You are not calling `callback` as a property of any object, like `lol.callback()`. Note that you don't really need the function to be property of some object to get what you want, you can also say `callback.call(lol, "HAmmer time")` which will explicitly bind `this` to `lol` for the call. Or in your example `callback.call( obj2, "Hammer Time.")`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That implies that obj2 is always the one calling. What if func3a is called by several objects. How do I assign the correct reference in the call method?

Comment: pass in the caller to func3a.

Comment: Is it generally acceptable practice to pass around object references and their callback methods?

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestion, which works perfectly.